# What's the default way to interpret the phrase "Don't waste any time (in) getting back here."?

Tags: ambiguity

Is this phrase ambiguous or is there are clearly preferred way of interpretation? The following 2 interpretations seem diametrically opposed:

1. Don't waste any time getting back because you'll be too late anyways. Focus on something else instead.
2. Hurry up. Make the trip as quick possible because you are needed urgently.

Is it context dependent?

Comment: Absent context it's ambiguous.

Comment: It's slightly ambiguous, but the fact that it's "getting back" instead of "coming back" suggests that the person is already in-transit or already planning to travel.

Comment: With the phrasing *Don't waste any time getting back here*, I would think the *hurry up* interpretation. For the *don't bother* interpretation, I would say something like: *Please don't waste your time trying to get back here.*

Comment: Don’t worry about getting back here because....

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this could, technically, be ambiguous. However, colloquially, it's quite clear the sentence refers to your second interpretation. "Don't waste any time doing x" is a common phrase to suggest that they need to do x and *only* x in a timely manner.

If they were saying they shouldn't come, they'd use "Don't waste *your* time" or "Don't waste *my* time" (if they wanted to particularly point out their annoyance), rather than "Don't waste *any* time".

Comment: Finding a supporting reference (interpretation B, not A, is the default) could be tricky here. have you tried?